# Getting node ID for jstree when using spearate menu and jstree-grid

Tags: jquery, events, tree, grid, jstree

My jstree uses jstree-grid, and one of the columns includes an action menu (which is generated by separate code, and all I need to do is apply the class "actionHandler" to generate the menu at runtime). This action menu consists of some extra div's, ul's and li's, which pretty much drowns the **click event** in HTML code.

What I want to accomplish is the following:

When the admin_new (representing 'new node') choice is clicked, I want to be able to retrieve the ID of the node for which the generated menu was clicked, in order to append this node as a child for the current node.

This is my current code:

```
jQuery("#structureBuilderTable").jstree({
           json_data: {data: testData},
           themes: {
                theme : "apple",
                dots : false,
                icons : false
           },
           plugins: ["json_data", "crrm", "ui", "themes", "grid"],
           core: {initially_open: [1]},
           grid : {
                 columns: [
                    {width: 200, header: "Title"},
                    {value:"id", width: 50, header: "id"},
                    {value:"logicalTitle", width: 50, header:"logical title"},
                    {width: 100, header:"handlinger", cellClass:'actionHandler'},
                    {value:"resource", width: 200, header:"resource"}
                 ]
           }
        }).bind("loaded_grid.jstree", function()
          {
          generateActionMenu("span.actionHandler",{
            admin_new: function(e){
              var nodeID = $(e.target).parents(/* Need an unique property*/).data('id');
            },
            admin_delete: function(e){
                /* delete node*/
            }, 'admin_open');
            });
```

And this is my dummy JSON:

```
var testData = [
            {
                data: "Seksjon1",
                attr: {id:"1", logicalTitle:"r2d2", resource:"videofile"},
                children: [
                    {
                        data: "Flersvar",
                        attr: {id:"2", logicalTitle:"c3p0", resource:"checkbox"}
                    },
                    {
                        data: "Flashtest",
                        attr: {id:"3", logicalTitle:"d2r2", resource:"flash"}
                    }
                ]
            }];
```

The main problem is that since no node is selected, I don't have access to any jstree specific events (giving access to the data object, which could've potentially solved the problem).

So, the question is basically: How can I retrieve relevant node information without directly manipulating the tree?

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated! (Sorry for the wall of text :p)

Comment: I actually got it to work now, by adding an extra class to the encapsulating <li>, and then backtracking to that particular tag using
`$(e.target).parents(className)`

However, if there's a better solution, I'd love some input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been posted: see my comment.